# matplotlib animation IOError [Error32] Broken pipe (using anaconda)

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ioerror

When trying to create an animation and save it to a file, I get that error.

my code:

```
def animate_scatter(x_val, y_val, z_vals,
                        divisions, name, z_max, z_min, units, radius):
    """
    Specific animator.
    """
    try:
        z_val = decompress(z_vals.pop(0), level=settings.medium_comp_level)
    except IndexError:
        return
    plt.cla()
    plt.clf()
    rad = float(radius*1.3)/divisions
    size = (rad/4)**2
    x_min = min(x_val)-rad*1.1
    x_max = max(x_val)+rad*1.1
    y_min = min(y_val)-rad*1.1
    y_max = max(y_val)+rad*1.1
    plt.xlim((x_min, x_max))
    plt.ylim((y_min, y_max))
    #plt.suptitle(name)
    plt.scatter(x_val, y_val, s=size, c=z_val, marker='s',
                vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    cb = plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel("x [pixels]")
    plt.ylabel("y [pixels]")
    cb.set_label(units)

def create_scatter_animation(x_val, y_val, z_vals_avg, divisions, z_max, z_min, units, name, radius=800, fps=15):
    """
    Creates animation from data.
    """
    fig = plt.figure()
    frames = len(z_vals_avg)
    def animate(dummy_frame):
        """
        Wrapper.
        """
        animate_scatter(x_val, y_val, z_vals_avg,
                            divisions, name, z_max, z_min, units, radius)
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames)
    anim.save(name, writer=WRITER, fps=fps)


def import_and_plot(source, radius=None, level=9):
    """
    Imports data from a compressed file and plots it.
    """
    src = open(source, 'r')
    values = decompress(src.read(), level=level)
    #[x_val, y_val, z_vals_avg, divisions, z_max, z_min, units]
    x_val, y_val, z_vals_avg = values[0], values[1], values[2]
    divisions = values[3]
    z_max, z_min = values[4], values[5]
    units = values[6]
    src.close()
    create_scatter_animation(x_val, y_val, z_vals_avg, divisions, z_max, z_min, units, source)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_data.py", line 5, in <module>
    plot()
  File "/home/jaime/Dropbox/TFG/rod-analysis/4090_42Hz/methods.py", line 795, in plot_all_data_files
    import_and_plot(file_)
  File "/home/jaime/Dropbox/TFG/rod-analysis/4090_42Hz/methods.py", line 773, in import_and_plot
    create_scatter_animation(x_val, y_val, z_vals_avg, divisions, z_max, z_min, units, source)
  File "/home/jaime/Dropbox/TFG/rod-analysis/4090_42Hz/methods.py", line 758, in create_scatter_animation
    anim.save(name, writer=WRITER, fps=fps)
  File "/home/jaime/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 810, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "/home/jaime/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 230, in grab_frame
    dpi=self.dpi, **savefig_kwargs)
  File "/home/jaime/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1565, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jaime/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 196, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jaime/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2232, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/jaime/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 519, in print_raw
    fileobj.write(renderer._renderer.buffer_rgba())
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I have tried solution in ["IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" when saving animation files in anaconda python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516426/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-when-saving-animation-files-in-anaconda-python)
 but it doesn't work for me. I am also using anaconda in ubuntu.

```
_writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
WRITER = _writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='name'), bitrate=1800)
```

Comment: Only happens in 1 of my pcs, so I suppose its a problem of package dependencies or something.

Comment: what is `WRITER`? and do you have ffmpeg correctly installed on all of your machines?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that part

Comment: I get the same error using conda's ffmpeg:

    conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/mutirri ffmpeg

Comment: That is not an officially package and it is broken (running fmpeg) from the command line falls

Comment: Yes, but in other pc it works